# Non-consumable In app purchase iOS(products with different price tiers)

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my app,which is already in the appstore,I want to add in app purchase for the subscription of videos and video seasons(Purchasing an entire season as well as individual videos with varying prices).So,different price tires are required.How can i do that?do we need different app id for different price tier?Any suggestions??

It is my doubt.If i am wrong,please correct me.

Comment: Are you talking about regular non-cosumables or subscriptions?

Comment: Actually i have to implement both.subscriptions as well as non consumable purchases.I am a beginner.Dont know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Subscription is different type of in-app purchase other than consumable and non consumable. You can use this library to integrate subscription into you code

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

[image]

Comment: For non-renewing subscription you can follow this link -

http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial

Comment: thanks,But there are no proper tutorials for MKStoreKit.Can we do it without MKStorekit?

Comment: What about dynamic price of the products?How to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can do it without any third party library. You can use your own source code, this third party library only for your help. This will save you time :)

Comment: For dynamic price you can check this post: http://latticelabs.com/blog/2014/07/simple-dynamic-pricing-mobile-games-apps/